# Angular 2 Component name duplicated

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

a newbie to Angular 2. Creating an app, components are placed in relevant folder as shown in attached pic. Structure is as:

```
- app
--components
---users
----create
----edit
---collaborations
----create
----edit
```

**On build (ng serve) error: ERROR in [default]**

```
...\src\app\app.module.ts:9:9    Duplicate identifier 'CreateComponent'.
```

How can I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are tring to import `CreateComponent` twice. When you import that you are actually adding the class! So go into one of those component files and rename the components class. Then change it in the required field.

First component

```
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Second component

```
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Now to import them,

```
import { FirstComponent }                          from "./first-component";
import { SecondComponent }                          from "./second-component";
```

Also you are calling it multiple times in your declarations. You need to call each one once. Make sure to name them differently and then add each one to the declarations.

Comment: It looks like renaming, or creating components with different names. Is there any other way to fix ?